# How do browsers handle "setInterval" and "Event Listener" differently?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval, event-listener

So I was wondering. What is the difference between this code:

```
windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
setInterval(function(){
    if(window.innerHeight != windowHeight || window.innerWidth != windowWidth){
         windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
         windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
         // do something here
    }
}, 10)
```

And this code?:

```
document.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    // do something here
})
```

I know the later method is the best practice. But what I want to know is how does browser handle event listeners any differently than checking for the event change at an interval of time? If the browsers work it differently then how?

And also what is the best way to create my own listener? For example like creating something like angular's `$watch()` function, but in plain Javascript.

Comment: because the event listener is only triggered when the action happens vs you checking constantly for a change?? It is like looking out the window for the pizza man every few seconds vs just waiting for him to ring the doorbell.

Comment: They are completely different. setInterval calls a function every `x` ms, while adding an event listener such as this will trigger the call back function when the document is resized

Comment: Also, doing work like that on the "resize" event is **not** "best practice", at least not without some sort of temporal buffering.

Comment: simple: since the browser knows when the window is resized, it doesn't keep checking. same as a user click() event: it just happens out of nowhere on a higher or lower level.

Comment: The browser doesn't need to check if the window has been resized, the operating system notifies the browser application when it happens.

Comment: @Barmar - That is what I wanted to know that there is a OS level event listener also happening in the background. Thank you very much.

Comment: Except for @Pointy rest of the facts were was known to me. What do you mean by 'some sort of temporal buffering'?

Comment: @Roy the "resize" event is fired **very** aggressively by browsers. If you do DOM queries and DOM updates in the "resize" handler, you're really taxing client resources. It's better to introduce some timed delays so that you only perform updates at some maximum frequency by using `setTimeout()` etc.

Comment: @epascarello In your analogy if Pizza delivery is the `event` and `setInterval` is checking if it arrived, then what is the doorbell? The `eventListener`? But in programming the `event` itseft doesn't trigger anything, there is something else that **listens** if the `event` occurred. Am I right?

Comment: @Barmar I guess it *might* be the OS/window environment that drives "resize" updates, but is that true when (for example) you've hit CTRL-SHIFT-M in Firefox to allow intra-window resizing?

Comment: In that case the browser is reacting to the mouse click and mouse movement events sent by the OS. When it processes them and determines that they're resizing a frame, it sends the resize event to the Javascript application in the frame.

Comment: @Roy The doorbell is the operating system processing input devices, your ears are the Javascript event listener code (which is why it's called a "listener").

Comment: @Barmar yes OK I was just curious; I have a very weak understanding of how browsers make use of native platform UI constructs (like "windows").

Comment: @Pointy The general idea is that operations on windows and standard controls within windows (like drop-down menus) are handled by the OS/window system, other operations within windows are handled by the application itself. The details depend on the specific OS and UI library.